# how to get popup calender in JSF1.2

Tags: javascript, jsf-1.2

How do i get popup calender in jsf1.2? I am not able get popup calender in jsf1.2. I Tried javascripts but it didt work. since its jsf1.2 it does not have support for ajax. Is there any posibility to get popup calender in jsf1.2?

Comment: Richfaces 3.x has a popup datepicker: http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=calendar&skin=blueSky

Comment: im using jsf1.2.. i cant use richfaces or primefaces.. is there any possibility to get pop up calender in jsf1.2 itself..

Comment: Richfaces 3.3.3 is built for JSF 1.2, Richfaces 4 is built for JSF 2 onwards